# How to push Account changes down Account Hierarchy

Tags: flow, governorlimits

I need to push some field updates, down to all the hierarchy of accounts.

I created a flow, which goes over all accounts with the parentId I need

[image]

Step details:

[image]

I auto-launch this with a process:

[image]

For some reason, on small trees (and/or even just a branch of the large tree), all is working. On larger trees (100 more accounts in 4 levels hierarchy) I get an error:

***The record couldn’t be saved because it failed to trigger a flow. A flow trigger failed to execute the flow with version ID 301D0000000LCxX. Contact your administrator for help.***

[image]

Error is: Loop Through Children

[image]

- Is that some type of execution limit?
- Memory limit?

How to check each please?

-- Apparently, I also get another error in the log:

**Error Occurred: Too many SOQL queries: 101**

So my question will be: How can I over come this on large trees?

Comment: Can you please let us know what you're doing in your update? The level of complexity impacts the answer

Comment: Trying to update a simple pick list value. That needs to be the same on all the tree

Comment: So I've run into something like this before with multi-hierarchy and Flow.  The way I actually solved it was to take a step back and use Process Builder.  You can do an update on "Child Records".  Have you tried to do it that way?

Comment: OMG, how did I miss that one. Thanks David, that's the solution I needed. *post as answer to accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I've run into something like this before with multi-hierarchy and Flow. The way I actually solved it was to take a step back and use Process Builder. You can do an update on "Child Records" and it will cascade down as the "Child Records" trigger the Process Builder again.

Select to Update Record

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this in a bulkified manner in flows, you need to use an assignment element in your loop to add each record to an sobject collection, and then use a single fast update element to update the sobject collection.  Otherwise your transaction will fail when there are more than 100 records in your loop as you are running an update on each record.

There is a great free hands on training by mvp for using loops and fast elements on this page

http://www.salesforce.com/campaigns/success-services/sfu-hands-on-training-sessions.jsp

Scroll down till you see the videos, and look for Build Advanced Flow with Loops and Fast Elements

Process builder is also a good option, as suggested by David.